# Qunit shows the result from another test

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, qunit

I would like to use unit testing for JavaScript in TeamCity.
I am using QUnit, phantomjs and QUnitTeamCityDriver.

But I have some problem. I get the following test result:

```
##teamcity[testFailed type='comparisonFailure' name='Check myFunction1> Expected 1 assertions, but 2 were run']
```

Here is my test:

```
asyncTest("Check myFunction1", function () {
    $.mockjaxClear();
    $.mockjax({
        url: "www.someUrl.com",
        responseText: '[{"Uid": "1"}]'
    });

    var real = window.getUrl;
    window.getUrl = function (rowdata, readonly, controller, action) {
        start();
        equal(controller, "Encounter");
        equal(action, "Save");

        window.getUrl = real;
    };

    myFunction1("123", false, "Encounter", "Save");
});
```

If I run a single test, it works correctly.
If I run a lot of tests, an error occurs.
In the test, I obviously do not indicate how many assertions I expect in this test, why do I get such a result?

Please, can some help me? How can I fix this problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in the number of assertions in your tests?

It is good practice to do that for all of your tests, especially asynchronous ones.  That way, you know for sure that all of your assertions get tested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I tried it. But in this case I get results from another test too. I also observe one interesting moment: when I run my test with help qunit html page, test is ok, but when I run test using team city scripts, test can fail or end successfully.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on @MForMarlon's answer:

> But in this case I get results from another test too.

I have noticed that I get an extra failing assertion when there is an error in teardown. Do you have a teardown function in module()?